# Mounting internal drive to be shared between users

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, mount, user

I have a question regarding drive mounts.

I installed Elementary on a separate SSD. 3 partitions - swap, file system and home.

I then installed a 1TB hard drive. The drive was partitioned to ext4 and mounts as `/media/user1/Drive`

What I then did was add another user - user2 as a standard desktop user.

When I log into user2, the drive appears in the sidebar of Files as "Drive" but when I click on it, I get a note something like you do not have permission etc.

So I edited the `/etc/fstab` to mount the drive at startup. Though I wanted to mount the drive as `/mnt/Drive`. So that's what I put in the `/etc/fstab` entry.
It worked, so user2 can access the drive through the folder `/mnt/Drive` with full read write access but, it doesn't appear under Devices in Files sidebar. The orginal entry - `/media/user1/Drive` - still appears in the sidebar but still no permission.

What I would like to do is mount the drive for both users in `/mnt/Drive` and have the drive appear under devices in the Files sidebar as Drive for both users.

Is there any reason why internal drive gets mounted as `/media/user1/Drive` but then doesn't share it? Does it matter if it is changed to `/mnt/Drive`?

Any help appreciated, best alternative solutions etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try method described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/351991/mounting-disk-drives-among-different-users. It worked OK for me. Note however that the last command given should be `sudo chgrp <groupname> <mountpoint>`